# Architecture style for uber like application

Tags: architecture, software-design, software-quality, requirements-management

I am creating architecture and design for a uber like android application. I want to ask which architecture style(layered,mvc,pipe and filter or etc) would be more appropriate for such application? And why? I know for many android apps mvc would be the best option but I'm still asking to clear any doubts..

Answer (score 0):

VIPER is best suited for this 
But UBER first used MVC but on expanding it failed to support it ..
So they shifted to VIPER and now use a hybrid architecture.
This detail can be founded on their website.